# Which registry keys control Alt+Tab task switcher in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, task-switching

I can see that utilities like WinAeroTweaker control look and behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> task switcher in Windows 10. But I cannot install them in company laptop.

**What are the equivalent Registry keys to do these changes?**

I especially need to get more than 4×4 window thumbnails in task swapper to avoid hiding rest of thumbnails (because the grid content scrolls to display more items, what is inconvenient.)

But besides of that, I would welcome more complete list of registry keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Take backup of Registry before you do any changes**

1. Go to Registry (Regedit)

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
2. Right-click on Explorer key and select **New** > **Key** menu item.
3. It will create a new key under **Explorer** key, set the name of new key as **`MultitaskingView`**.
   [image: MultiTaskView snap Techie]
4. Create DWORDs which can be created to customize UI Alt Tab View. Right Click on `AltTabViewHost` and select **New** > **DWORD (32 bit) Value**.
5. For example use **Value Name** `Wallpaper` and give it **Value Data** `0` or `1`. Check the difference.
6. You can see all Values available to customization in the list below (Edit: link to PDF at GoogleDrive was removed in order to avoid possible link rot).

---

Possible key names, data types and their default values:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MultitaskingView\AltTabViewhost]
"Grid_leftmargin"=dword:0000005A
"Grid_rightmargin"=dword:0000005A
"Grid_topmargin"=dword:00000028
"Grid_bottommargin"=dword:00000028
"Grid_adjacentspacing"=dword:00000009
"Grid_rowspacing"=dword:0000000A
"Thumbnail_min_width"=dword:0000004B
"Thumbnail_min_height_percent"=dword:0000000F
"Thumbnail_max_height_percent"=dword:00000028
"Thumbnail_max_aspectratio"=dword:00000096
"Thumbnail_icon_size"=dword:0000001E
"Thumbnail_icon_plate"=dword:00000018
"Thumbnail_label_leftmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_label_rightmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_label_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_label_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_leftmargin"=dword:0000005
"Thumbnail_hover_rightmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_hover_topmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_hover_bottommargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_icon_rightmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_topmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_color"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_percent"=dword:00000036
"Thumbnail_focus_border_width"=dword:00000002
"Thumbnail_focus_border_color"=dword:00FFFFFF
"Thumbnail_focus_percent"=dword:00000064
"Thumbnail_mousedown_shrinkpercent"=dword:0000005F
"Thumbnail_closebutton__width"=dword:0000001E
"Thumbnail_closebutton__height"=dword:0000001E
"ScrollButtonContainer_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_buttonspacing"=dword:0000000F
"ScrollButtonContainer_button__width"=dword:00000069
"ScrollButtonContainer_button__height"=dword:00000028
"Desktop_background_margin_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_background_margin_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_background_margin_topmargin"=dword:00000014
"Desktop_background_margin_bottommargin"=dword:0000000
"Desktop_background_color"=dword:001D1D1D
"Desktop_layout_margin_leftmargin"=dword:0000000A
"Desktop_layout_margin_rightmargin"=dword:0000000A
"Desktop_layout_margin_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_layout_margin_bottommargin"=dword:0000000F
"Desktop_item_spacing"=dword:0000000A
"Desktop_click_scale"=dword:0000005F
"Desktop_rest_overlay_alpha"=dword:0000008A
"New_button_glyph_size"=dword:0000000C
"New_button_plate"=dword:0000000C
"New_button_plate_hover"=dword:00121212
"New_button_glyph_color"=dword:00FFFFFF
"New_button_focus_margins_leftmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_rightmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_topmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_bottommargin"=dword:00000010
"Desktop_closebutton__width"=dword:0000001E
"Desktop_closebutton__height"=dword:0000001E
"DimmingLayer_percent"=dword:00000023
"Wallpaper"=dword:00000001
"DimmingLayer_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Grid_Desktop_margin"=dword:000000F
"Desktop_height"=dword:00000078
```

(Source: [Registry customization for MultitaskingView (MTV) aka alt-tab, task view, and snap assist](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_personal/registry-customization-for-multitaskingview-mtv/806a0c84-b203-46fb-b23a-acc82dc0ecce?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies%2CAllReplies%2CAllReplies))

Comment: Credits: source appears to be this link: [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_personal/registry-customization-for-multitaskingview-mtv/806a0c84-b203-46fb-b23a-acc82dc0ecce?tab=question&status=AllReplies&status=AllReplies%2CAllReplies%2CAllReplies) because all keys and their default values are exactly the same.

Comment: I taught of putting the values in answer itself but answer will be lengthy so I moved to PDF in Google drive

Comment: No problem. As you can see, the site handles longer lists by keeping them smaller (with added scrollbars) so the list looks acceptable. It is better to have all necessary resources directly in the answer because external links may break and the answer will be no longer helpful.

Comment: Yes you are true..going forward I will follow the same thank you.

Comment: @TechieGossip, we appreciate your contributions and that is certainly a good answer, but unless you essentially devised that solution yourself, you really should reference your source within the post.

Comment: @Run5k. Sure do the same.. even I have tested in my laptop and posted it..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get what I wanted thanks to the accepted answer, which is LARGE icons and small thumbnails. It allows for ~35 thumbnails to be shown simultaneously.

You need to lower `Thumbnail_min_height_percent` to get smaller thumbnails and allow for more space for other more thumbnails to fit.

Here's what I ended up using:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MultitaskingView\AltTabViewhost]
"Grid_leftmargin"=dword:0000005a
"Grid_rightmargin"=dword:0000005a
"Grid_topmargin"=dword:00000028
"Grid_bottommargin"=dword:00000028
"Grid_adjacentspacing"=dword:00000001
"Grid_rowspacing"=dword:0000000a
"Thumbnail_min_width"=dword:0000004b
"Thumbnail_min_height_percent"=dword:00000006
"Thumbnail_max_height_percent"=dword:00000014
"Thumbnail_max_aspectratio"=dword:000000c8
"Thumbnail_icon_size"=dword:00000030
"Thumbnail_icon_plate"=dword:00000030
"Thumbnail_label_leftmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_label_rightmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_label_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_label_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_leftmargin"=dword:00000010
"Thumbnail_hover_rightmargin"=dword:00000010
"Thumbnail_hover_topmargin"=dword:00000010
"Thumbnail_hover_bottommargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_icon_rightmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_topmargin"=dword:00000005
"Thumbnail_icon_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_color"=dword:00000000
"Thumbnail_hover_percent"=dword:00000016
"Thumbnail_focus_border_width"=dword:00000120
"Thumbnail_focus_border_color"=dword:00ffc73f
"Thumbnail_focus_percent"=dword:00000064
"Thumbnail_mousedown_shrinkpercent"=dword:00000050
"Thumbnail_closebutton__width"=dword:00000010
"Thumbnail_closebutton__height"=dword:00000010
"ScrollButtonContainer_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"ScrollButtonContainer_buttonspacing"=dword:0000000f
"ScrollButtonContainer_button__width"=dword:00000069
"ScrollButtonContainer_button__height"=dword:00000028
"Desktop_background_margin_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_background_margin_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_background_margin_topmargin"=dword:00000014
"Desktop_background_margin_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_background_color"=dword:001d1d1d
"Desktop_layout_margin_leftmargin"=dword:0000000a
"Desktop_layout_margin_rightmargin"=dword:0000000a
"Desktop_layout_margin_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"Desktop_layout_margin_bottommargin"=dword:0000000f
"Desktop_item_spacing"=dword:0000000a
"Desktop_click_scale"=dword:0000005f
"Desktop_rest_overlay_alpha"=dword:0000008a
"New_button_glyph_size"=dword:0000000c
"New_button_plate"=dword:0000000c
"New_button_plate_hover"=dword:00121212
"New_button_glyph_color"=dword:00ffffff
"New_button_focus_margins_leftmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_rightmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_topmargin"=dword:00000010
"New_button_focus_margins_bottommargin"=dword:00000010
"Desktop_closebutton__width"=dword:00000018
"Desktop_closebutton__height"=dword:00000018
"DimmingLayer_percent"=dword:00000000
"Wallpaper"=dword:00000001
"DimmingLayer_leftmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_rightmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_topmargin"=dword:00000000
"DimmingLayer_bottommargin"=dword:00000000
"Grid_Desktop_margin"=dword:0000000f
"Desktop_height"=dword:00000078
```