# Make Alt + Tab Task Switcher show more tasks at once [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

This is related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/31344/how-do-i-change-the-alt-tab-task-switcher-window-to-show-more-applications) old question, but the answers are outdated.

The Alt+Tab task switcher is extremely useful, but it has a maximum number of task sit shows at once until it applies some paging/Scrolling behavior that prevents you from seeing all at once. The maximum seems to be 4 x 4 task previews, and that is despite there being plenty more room on the screen.

Is there a way to tweak this number?
The linked question's accepted answer listed some registry keys, but those seem to have been for the old alt+tab behavior and aren't used for the new one. Otherwise changing two numbers in the registry would be a perfect solution.
Another reply there advised using the "Alt+Tab Tuner", but its website basically said it's dead and superseded by the "Winaero Tweaker" - which has a fun option to dim the background when altTabbing, but no option to increase the number of previews shown at once.

Is there a way to achieve the behavior I want? To make windows show the previews of more than 4x4 windows at once? If there isn't a simple registry key additional software might be an option as well.

[edit]
[Which registry keys control Alt+Tab task switcher in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1230879/which-registry-keys-control-alttab-task-switcher-in-windows-10)
A similar question that has a bunch of interesting registry keys to play around with. Sadly nothing that really solves my problem. I have a big monitor and I'd like the "Grid" aka the dark gray background the thumbnails are placed on to be a lot bigger than it is, almost touching the borders of my screen instead of being centered in the middle. Sadly everything that seems possible with the keys given is adjust the margin between the inner borders of the gray rectangle and the grid content that fills it. Maybe that's a key somewhere else? It feels like a parameter that SHOULD be changeable

Answer (score 1):

To change the number of rows and columns for the Classic Alt+Tab Dialog:

- [Enable the classic Alt+Tab dialog](https://winaero.com/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/) if needed
- Open the Registry Editor app (`regedit`)
- Go to the following Registry key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
- On the right, modify or create a new STRING (REG_SZ) value
  named `CoolSwitchRows`. This will define the number of rows for
  the classic dialog. The default is 3, and the value range is from 1 to 20.
- Under the same key, modify or create a new STRING (REG_SZ) value named
  `CoolSwitchColumns`. This will define the number of columns for classic dialog. The default is 7, and the value range is from 1 to 43.
- To enable these changes you need to sign out and sign back in to your
  account.

Source :
[Change Number of Rows and Columns for Classic Alt+Tab Dialog](https://winaero.com/change-number-of-rows-and-columns-for-classic-alttab-dialog/).

Comment: Note: This answer is the same basically as in your old question link. Perhaps it didn't work for you because you haven't enabled the classic Alt+Tab dialog .

Comment: Of course, I saw this in the linked question, I even referenced it in my original one here. The problem is that this only works for the old/classic dialog which is not what I want. I want big previews and not just icons. The most common use-case for having more than 16 windows open at once and wanting to switch, at least for me, is multiple instances of the same thing, like having a bunch of pictures open to compare.

Comment: As far as I know such a tweak exists only for the classic Alt+Tab. You could try [third-party alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=Alt%2BTab), but I have not ever tried one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be aware of <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Windows+Tab is a similar keyboard shortcut to Alt+Tab. It opens the Task View interface, which offers a thumbnail view of your open windows and even multiple desktops you can arrange them on. It also includes the Windows Timeline, but you can disable it if you prefer.

Comment: I am aware of that shortcut, although admittedly I have either always missed the timeline aspect or haven't noticed it since we got it. Either way - to switch to your desired task from there  you need to also use the mouse, which is what I want to avoid here to begin with (unless you tab through *that* interface but it's as tedious as using a random website and tabbing through all the interactables)